# Cannot Rename/Move folder in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, onedrive

I am trying to use Sharepoint as a fileserver to host a folder and share it out with sync in OneDrive.
I have create a SitePages and a main folder.

Folder contains circa 100gb in 385 sub folder, about 150.000 files.

When I try to rename i get this error:

"The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator."

I have also notice I am not able to move the folder to a root folder. I dont have the "move"
option. 
I have tried to use file explorer but is not available.
I read to make it available I had to emulate Internet Explorer 10 or previos version, this leads to make the option visible but nothing happen when I click on it.

Comment: This is no answer. Filtering the folder to produce a few or even zero files does not work either. Powershell also fails in renaming. I can not believe we are stuck with not being able to simply rename a folder.. :-(

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in SharePoint. If your view contains more than 5 thousands items you will get this error. However, it is notable - SharePoint list contain 30 million item, but at any point of times, the item view should not load more than 5k items. You can split your view into multiple views with the metadata filter conditions and ensure the query or filter returns less than 5k items.